# Running Windows 10 and ScrapeBox

Tags: pi-3, windows

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and was wondering if you could install Windows 10 for the Raspberry Pi 3 and run ScrapeBox software from the Raspberry Pi running Windows 10.  Does anyone know if this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can make out from their [website](http://www.scrapebox.com/), scrapebox is Windows only. That's going to rule it out for use on the Pi, even running Windows 10 IoT (which [doesn't run 'normal' Windows programs](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42120/is-it-possible-to-install-exe-file-in-raspberry-pi-running-windows-10-iot-core)). Unfortunately it's a 'no' on this one.

Comment: Is there some hardware like the raspberry  pi that can run Windows 10?

Comment: That's a very different question, and out of scope for this site as it's not Raspberry Pi related. It might be worth a look at something like the [LattePanda](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/139108638/lattepanda-a-45-win10-computer-for-everything)?